# MVC: what code belongs to the model

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp

I've started development on a CakePHP project since a few weeks now. Since the beginning I was struggling with the amount of code inside the controllers. The controllers have, in most cases more lines of code than the models. By knowing the expression "Skinny controller, fat model" I'm searching for some days now for a way to put more code in the models.

The question arises at this point is, "where to draw the line". What should the controller do and what should the model do. There are already some questions/answers on this only I'm searching for a more practical explanation. For example I've put a function below which is now inside the controller. I think a part of this code must and can be moved to the model. So my question is: what part can I move to the model and what can remain in the controller.

```
/**
* Save the newly added contacts and family members.
*/
public function complete_contacts()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if (isset($this->data['FamilyMembers'])) { 

            $selected_user = $this->Session->read('selected_user');

            $family_members = $this->data['FamilyMembers'];

            $this->ContactsConnection->create();
            foreach ($family_members as $family_member) { 
                // connection from current user to new user
                $family_member['ContactsConnection']['contact_family_member_id'] = $selected_user['id'];
                $family_member['ContactsConnection']['nickname'] = $selected_user['first_name'];
                $this->ContactsConnection->saveAll($family_member);

                // inverted connection from new user to current user
                $inverted_connection['ContactsConnection']['family_member_id'] = $selected_user['id'];
                $inverted_connection['ContactsConnection']['contact_family_member_id'] = $this->FamilyMember->inserted_id;
                $inverted_connection['ContactsConnection']['nickname'] = $family_member['FamilyMember']['nickname'];
                $this->ContactsConnection->saveAll($inverted_connection);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Should I create a function in the FamilyMember model called: "save_new_family_member($family_member, $selected_user)"?

Comment: Your code only allows a FamilyMember to be saved by using a perfectly-crafted POST request. What if you wish to create a FamilyMember from somewhere else, like a shell or a test case? It would make more sense to provide a proper API for your FamilyMember model rather than only providing a RESTful one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as the purposes of the M and the C

> The model manages the behavior and data of the application domain,
> responds to requests for information about its state (usually from the
> view), and responds to instructions to change state (usually from the
> controller).
>
> The controller receives user input and initiates a response by making
> calls on model objects. A controller accepts input from the user and
> instructs the model and a view port to perform actions based on that
> input.

I would suggest you can pass

```
    $selected_user = $this->Session->read('selected_user');
```

To your Model and perform your for each inside of your Model.  You may want to change rules as to how the data is stored or perform some transformations on it and the Controller should be blind to this.  Basically use the Controller to get your information [from the View often] to the Model.  Don't directly manipulate the Model from the Controller.  In short YES create the function that you suggested :)

That being said sometimes I find myself in a position where my Controller has to do more than I'd like, in which case at least break the task down into helper methods that way your controller is more manageable and you can reuse code where needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right.

You can of course create some methods in model and make it fat with:

```
function updateContactFamilyMemberId($id){}
function updateNickname($nickname){}
...
```

In my opinion it still will be correct, but unnecessary.